# Find and rename double quotes contains files in directory

Tags: shell, rename

I'm trying to rename files contains double quotes with file name in directory.

> /tables/ddl/ directory

```
"user".sql
"customer".sql
inventory.sql
"orders".sql
```

Would like to remove double quotes in file names which contains that.
Like this:

```
user.sql
customer.sql
inventory .sql
orders.sql
```

In my shell script, To find the files with double quotes i used find command with regax as follows. It shows list of files with double quotes.

> `find . -name '*["]*'`

Also i tried fo relaying directory and rename files.

```
for myfile in /tables/ddl/*; do
    echo $myfile
    rename 's,^[0-9]{2}\.,,' *sql
done
```

Is that possible to at the same time **find** and **rename** files contains with double quotes?

Comment: First of all, let me clarify what you really want to do. Do you want to
rename the files by removing two leading digits and the following dot *if* the filename
contains double quotes? I see some files in /tables/ddl/ contains
double quotes but none of them have leading digits. Would you please
update your question including the filenames which match the second
operation as well as the expected results?

Comment: Thanks @tshiono Forgot to add the desired result. Added that

Comment: Thank you for the prompt feedback. BTW what about the `rename 's,^[0-9]{2}\.,,' *sql` command? Are you just illustrating the usage of the `rename` command as an example?

Comment: Yes.  found regex command for rename text with special characters in another question. Used to explain problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the usage of the `rename` command in the second code, you seem to have the perl-based `rename` command available. (There are two different rename commands, one is perl-based, the other is not. Confusing.)
Then you can rename the files removing the double quotes just with:

```
rename 's/"//g' /tables/ddl/*.sql
```

- The first argument `s/"//g` is a perl statement which removes the double quotes.
- You can pass multiple files using the type-glob `*.sql` to the `rename` command at once.
- The command above does not affect the files which do not include double quotes.

**[Edit]**
Here is an alternative without the perl-based `rename` command:

```
find tables/ddl -type f -name '*"*' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    mv -- "$file" "$(sed 's/"//g' <<< "$file")"
done
```

- The usage of `find` command is almost same as yours.
- The `-print0` option specifies a null character (\0) as a delimiter of
  files to protect blank characters (whitespace, tab, etc.) in the
  filenames, if any.
- The `-d ""` option to `read` command corresponds to `-print0` above
  to split the input stream on null characters into filenames back again.
- The `sed 's/"//g' <<< "$file"` command removes double quotes
  from the filename.
- The command above assumes the directory name (`tables/ddl` here)
  does not include double quotes.

Or simply:

```
for file in tables/ddl/'"'*'"'.sql; do
    mv -- "$file" "$(sed 's/"//g' <<< "$file")"
done
```

The single quotes around the double quotes avoid the internal asterisk `*` to be wrapped with the double quotes.

Comment: Could you explain the other way(without using perl based command) you mention in solution. It will help also :)

Comment: Certainly. I've updated my answer adding an alternative without the perl-based `rename` command. Hope it helps.